# Where does the water in the Euphrates and Tigras rivers come from?

Tags: rivers, rainfall

The research I've done says that the rivers are fed by alpine snow, lakes and rains in the Taurus mountains but I'm specifically interested in whether the rains/snows and the water that feeds the lakes come from evaporation from the Mediterranean, or is it more from the Black sea or Caspian sea or somewhere else?

Comment: Have you looked into prevalent air currents in the region?